# jQuery form validation check ending up in a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, loops, submit

I'm very new if it comes to jQuery. I'm trying to make a good client-side validation for my form. (At the moment only checking if X field is not empty)

But when I submit the form I end up in a forever loop.

I can explain the problem, and I understand the 'why'. But I have no idea how to fix it.

The problem occurs because:
Everytime I submit the form, he runs the validation check again, then submits when there aren't any errors, but because I submit, he checks again-- and so on.

With this code I monitor if the form is getting submitted. (And if so, let the validation begin)

```
 // Form validation on submitting the form
  $('form').on('submit', function() {
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log('Form is submitted');

    submitFormValidation(id);
  });
```

With this code I'm trying to validate every input field.

```
 function submitFormValidation(id) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var goodCount = 0;
  var goodCountMinimum = $('#' + id + ' .c-contact-form-item-input').length;

  $('#' + id + ' .c-contact-form-item-input').each(function () {
    if ($(this).val().length == 0) {
      $(this).parent().find('span').css('background-color', 'red');
      $(this).parent().find('span').css('width', 'calc(100% - 30px');
      $(this).parent().find('i').css('background-color', 'red');
      $(this).parent().find('i').css('animation', 'none');
      $(this).parent().find('i').css('opacity', '1');
    }
    else {
      $(this).parent().find('span').css('background-color', 'green');
      $(this).parent().find('span').css('width', 'calc(100% - 30px');
      $(this).parent().find('i').css('background-color', 'green');
      $(this).parent().find('i').css('animation', 'none');
      $(this).parent().find('i').css('opacity', '1');

      goodCount = goodCount + 1;
      return goodCount;
    }
  });

  if (goodCount == goodCountMinimum) {
    $('#' + id).submit();
  }
}
```

I hope someone can help me out on how to fix the never ending loop.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Try changing...

```
$('#' + id).submit();
```

to...

```
$('#' + id)[0].submit();
```

The difference between these two is that the first triggers a submit on the jQuery object, where the second triggers a sumbit on the raw Element.  Triggering a submit on the Element, and not the jQuery object, should result in the jQuery submit event handler being skipped.

Example...

```js
$('form').on('submit', function(e){
  console.log('submitted!');
  e.preventDefault();
  
  setTimeout(function(){
    e.target.submit();
  }, 5000);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="http://www.google.com/">
  <button>Go!</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if (goodCount == goodCountMinimum) {
 $('#' + id).submit();
}
```

To

```
if (goodCount == goodCountMinimum) {
  return;
} else {
  e.preventDefault();//pass in the event object to the function
}
```

For this solution to work, change your function to take two parameters:

```
function submitFormValidation(id, e) {}
```

And invoke it like this:

```
$('form').on('submit', function(e) {
var id = $(this).attr('id');
console.log('Form is submitted');

submitFormValidation(id, e);
});
```

If you submit the form (using jQuery's `submit()`), the jQuery `submit` event handler will continuously be called. Just returning will allow the default action of the form to be taken (which is submitting).